# Checkbox inside Select Option vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a checkbox dropdown feature in vue ? or if someone has a working skeleton for it. Was just wondering as i couldn't really find anything on internet with respect to vue.

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361379/dropdown-bootstrap-menu-in-vuejs). It can be useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can use [Element UI#dropdown](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dropdown), which is ready to go component, also Element UI has dozens of other components you may need in future.

**Good Luck!**